# Not able to fetch mui-datagrid while writing test cases usiing jest framework

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a mui-datagrid in my react application.In the datagrid, some data with the headers ('CSA NAME', 'START DATE'). I would like to select all items in column 'CSA NAME' while writing test case in jest.used 'getAllByRole('cell', { description: /CSA NAME/i })'

but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to click to checkbox for select all items you could try to use something like this:

```
const tableCheckBoxes = screen.getAllByRole('checkbox', {name: '...'});
// you can set aria-label attribute to each checkbox for accessibility improvements and then get checkboxes by role and name additionally

userEvent.click(tableCheckBoxes[0]); 
// where tableCheckBoxes[0] is your select all checkbox
```

It should work in case if you have only table checkboxes on the page.

Comment: What should be the value of '...'?

Comment: The value should be the same as you set it into `aria-label` property